# Generate jwt token to create database in mongo - Azure

Tags: mongodb, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I need to create a database in azure using JavaScript and found the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/mongodbresources/createupdatemongodbdatabase) document.

By providing necessary details and clicking on **Try It**  button in the document works for me since it generates token once we sign in to azure account.

I tried *Authorization URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize* mentioned in the document using POSTMAN to create token. But it is not working for me. I tested with the clientID of the application which uses the database.

Is this the way to create token? or Is there any other method to create jwt to create database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Authorization URL* in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/mongodbresources/createupdatemongodbdatabase#security) uses [Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow). But it could not use POSTMAN to get token, because it needs to sign in with your account. The best way is using [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) in this case.

**Note:** Make sure the app you used to get the token has a role(e.g Owner/Contributor) in your subscription.

**Get access_token (client credentials flow):**

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token        //Line breaks for clarity

client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx
&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
&client_secret={value in client secrets}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

[image]

You will get the access_token and it can be used like below(from **Try It** button in the document). You could decode them at https://jwt.ms/.

[image]

---

**Add: Get access_token (Implicit grant flow)**

I don't recommend using this way(It's not safe enough), but you could learn as a reference.

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=xxxxxxxxxx
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri={the Redirect URI in your application}
&scope=openid https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
&prompt=none
&login_hint={your username}
```